# Product between a column vector and a row vector - error

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, warning-messages

I know that matrices product is correct when the number of the columns of the first matrix is equal to the number of rows of the second matrix.

Why I can't do the product between a column vector and a row vector in Mathematica? For example:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} \, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

Mathematica gives me the error: Dot::dotsh: Tensors {{1},{2},{3}} and {1,2,3} have incompatible shapes.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Try `{{1}, {2}, {3}}.{{1, 2, 3}}`

Comment: Thank you very much @Coolwater

Answer (score 6):

Remember that Mathematica does not distinguish between row vectors and column vectors: all vectors are seen as lists ([tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ScalarsVectorsAndMatrices.html)). You could convert each vector into a $1\times n$ matrix (row vector) and a $n\times1$ matrix (column vector), as @Mefitico suggests, and then matrix-multiply, Matlab-style. You could also stay with vectors-as-lists and do an outer product:

```
Outer[Times, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

or

```
KroneckerProduct[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you define a function to perform such products like:

```
VecProd[v__, u__] := Transpose[{u}].{v}
```

Then for your case:

```
VecProd[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

Evaluates to:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}, {3, 6, 9}}
```

This looks simple, but as a non frequent user, it becomes annoying to wrap my head around this particularity every time.

Comment: Your matching pattern seems off. I think it should be `VecProd[v_, u_] := ...` (or `VecProd[v_List, u_List] := ...` for clarity) since you'd never want this to match for more than 2 arguments.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit : Not sure if I understood your comment. I use double underscore characters because `u` and `v` are vectors with variable size, as opposed to a scalar but looking at [Wolfram Doccumentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Syntax.html) it seems unclear if that was necessary.

Comment: The pattern `v__` will not match a vector of variable size; it will match a sequence of arguments. For example, `VecProd[1,2,3,4,5,6]` will also match the pattern and give nonsense results. In that case, it matches `v` to `1` and `u` to `Sequence[2,3,4,5,6]`. A variable-length vector named `u` should be matched as `u : {__}` (list with 1 or more elements) or simply `u_List` (anything with the head `List`).

Comment: @SjoerdSmit : Thanks for the comment, I"ll check this later and update the answer.