# Row vectors and column vectors (Mathematica vs. MATLAB)

Tags: core-language, matlab

As far as I know, Mathematica does not distinguish between row vectors and column vectors: all vectors are seen as lists. I know ways to bypass this as suggested in [Product between a column vector and a row vector - error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162008/product-between-a-column-vector-and-a-row-vector-error) and get MATLAB-style matrix multiplication.

My question is why Mathematica and MATLAB behaves differently in this context?  I have seen a clear explanation in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica several years ago but I cannot recall it anymore.

I guess it has to do with something fundamental.

Comment: It's not so much that Mathematica doesn't distinguish between row and column vectors: it's more that it has a clear concept of tensors of arbitrary rank (something Matlab didn't really have last time I checked). A column vector is just a `n x 1` matrix and there's nothing stopping you from using `n x 1` matrices. But you don't have to if you don't want to. A normal list is just a rank 1 tensor. The documentation of `Dot`, for example, states that `Dot` contracts the innermost indices of two tensors. It doesn't matter what order of tensor you're using.

Comment: As in a slightly different way expressed by @Szabolcs as well, row and column vectors are not vectors themselves. They are only two different *notations* for the same vector. A vector cannot be transposed, a matrix can. Transposing a row or column vector is just switching from row notation to column notation or conversely. In *Mathematica*, this is completely superfluous.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a limitation of MATLAB, as MATLAB is only able to work with matrices. It does not have true vectors.  It cannot even represent a character array as a 1D array or a structure array as a single element—it always *must* be 2D.

Mathematica takes a much more general view. It works with arbitrary, $n$-index tensors. A 1-index tensor is called a vector. A 2-index one is called a matrix.

What is commonly called a "row vector" or a "column vector" is not really a *vector*. It is a $1\times k$ or a $k \times 1 $ *matrix*.

The dot product of a vector $v$ and a matrix $a$ is
$$u_j = \sum_i v_i a_{ij}$$

The product of $a$ and $v$ is
$$u_i = \sum_j a_{ij} v_j$$

In general, one can contract any two indices together, although `Dot` specifically only contracts the last one of the first tensor with the first one of the last tensor. `TensorContract` can do more general operations.

---

One particular limitation of Mathematica compared to MATLAB is that Mathematica cannot represent arrays where one of the dimensions is 0, e.g. a 0-by-n matrix. This is not due to the difference in philosophy that I described above. It's because Mathematca uses nested lists, so we can have a 1-by-0 `{}` but not a 0-by-1 thing.

Comment: I disagree that Matlab doesn't do 1D arrays — in fact I think it would be more correct to say that ALL Matlab arrays are 1D with an N-D size index as part of data structure. For instance, you can write `x=1:1000000;` which is 1D and then `xx=reshape(x,[10 10 10 10 10 10]);` which is very very fast, to turn it into a 6D array. And contents in all Matlab arrays can be indexed with a unity-length index. So `xx(600)` is the same as `x(600)` in the example I just mentioned.

Comment: @WillRobertson The fact that it's possible to do a 1D indexing has no bearing on how these quantities are treated during matrix multiplication. Also, while it _can_ indeed handle higher dimensional arrays, the C APIs don't accept setting the dimension to 1. The minimum is 2. It's clear that MATLAB was designed with matrices and only matrices in mind, to the extent that even a char, cell or struct is a two-index quantity.

Comment: Fair enough. I see what you mean in that a vector of length N is not (conceptually) the same as a matrix of length 1xN or Nx1. And that the internal data structure is not the same as the mathematical meaning.