# Doubt about tensor product of two column vectors

Tags: tensors

I want to get the tensor product of two column vectors, for example:

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {2, 3, 1};
psi0 = ArrayFlatten[TensorProduct[a, b]];
```

The size of `psi0` is $ 3 \times 3 $, but it should be a column vector with 9 components.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `Flatten` instead of `ArrayFlatten`?

Comment: Or maybe `ArrayFlatten[...,1]`?

Comment: BTW there are no "column vectors" in *Mathematica*. [See here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/200538/26598) [and here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197960/26598) for discussions.

Comment: thanks,  ArrayFlatten[...,1]

Comment: First, a row/column vector is somewhat a redundant choice in Wolfram language, which can be uniformly represented by a `List`. Then please compare `TensorProduct` and `KroneckerProduct`.

Answer (score 2):

As already noted, what is wanted can be obtained using either of `TensorProduct[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}]` or `KroneckerProduct[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}]`. Additionally, consider the following evaluations:

```
KroneckerProduct[{{1, 2, 3}}, {{2, 3, 1}}]
   {{2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 2, 6, 9, 3}}

KroneckerProduct[{{1}, {2}, {3}}, {{2}, {3}, {1}}]
   {{2}, {3}, {1}, {4}, {6}, {2}, {6}, {9}, {3}}
```