# Matrix Vector multiplication

Tags: matrix, vector

I have a rather simple question which surprisingly i could find the answer theres a matrix $U $ whith is $4*4$ and a vector $A$ which is $4*1$ and when I wand to multiply them by $U.A$ operator i get this :

Dot::rect: Nonrectangular tensor encountered.

so does anyone know how can i multiply them together?

```
U = {{1,2,1,1},{1,3,2,2},{0,2,0,1},{0,1,2,1}}
```

and

```
A = {{1},{1},{1},{1}}
```

Comment: Post your `U` and `A` please.

Comment: @Kiro Consider any arbitrry matrices i tried different matrices. all of the mgive me the same error regardless

Comment: Did you wrap `MatrixForm` around any of them during definition? This is a common pitfall: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/43522

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit Well actually I defined them using the toolbox basicmath assistant-> typesetting , which provide me an exat matrix form to fill

Comment: @Jason I can't reproduce your problem with arbitrary matrices.

Comment: @Kiro I added the matrices

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit In fact thank you so much cz that was the problem

Comment: Concerning your unusual form of `A`, [this discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/200538) and its [linked materials](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197958) may be of interest for you.