# Not getting evaluated output

Tags: matrix, evaluation, output

I just started using Mathematica.
When doing the matrix calculation I encountered some problem, output is not evaluated instead it just gives the input as the output.

Example:

[image: Example problem]

Comment: `MatrixForm` is an output wrapper that gets in the way of further evaluation. Use `(A = {....}) // MatrixForm` instead, so `A` is assigned the unmodified value and then that value is formatted for output by MatrixForm.

Comment: Yes, This solved the issue. Thanks @MarcoB

Comment: First of all welcome to Mathematica SE.! To make the most of the site start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). Check the site for similar questions first. After asking always [edit] if improbable, but not to move goalpost, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) NOT images**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Glad it helped! Note also that you don't have to define `V` as a list of lists to indicate a row vector. Mathematica does not need that distinction, so you can just write `v = {0, 1, 0}`. See also [Row vectors and column vectors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197958/27951).